# Log4net treat exceptions different from other log messages

Tags: c#, configuration, log4net

I want to set a pattern like this for exceptions:

```
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%-5level] %date{HH:mm:ss}: %message%newlineException: %exception{message}%newlineStackTrace: %exception{stacktrace}%newline" />
  </layout>
```

Whilst I want to set a pattern like this for non-exceptions:

```
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%-5level] %date{HH:mm:ss}: %message%newline" />
  </layout>
```

How can I accomplish this?

This is independant from log level, since it could be `DEBUG`, `DEBUG-EXCEPTION`, just as well as `ERROR` or `ERROR-EXCEPTION`

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for but I think it kind of does this already. As long as you log your exceptions like this:

```
try 
{
throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Log.Error("There was an exception!", ex)
}
```

Here's an example for PowerGUI VSX:

```
2012-01-25 23:04:21,539 [1] FATAL PowerGui.AddOn.PowerGuiComposer [(null)] - There was an unhandled exception! OMG WTF!
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'QuickConsole.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Engine, Version=3.1.0.2058, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a69c32b63191909f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
```